# count the weekend and holiday dates and sub struct it from 2 dates if it is between of it sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables with columns shown below,

- Holidays : `HolidayId, HolidayName, HolidayDate, Comment`
- Entitlements:
  `EntitlementId, EmployeeId, LeaveTypeId, LeavePeriodId, FromDate
  , UptoDate, Entitlementdays`
- Weekend: `WeekeindId, Weekends`

TODO:
**create a store procedure for insertion**  
Before insertion it should *check* and *count* the dates in `holiday` and `weekend` table
if it is between the date which is in the `startdate` and `enddate` of entitlement table should be subtract.
in sql

Comment: what kind of program do you use? That way we know what kind of syntax we need

Comment: which RDBMS do u use ?

Comment: i use sql server and mvc 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as you already have weekend table and holiday table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
usp_LeaveDays (@employeeid int) 
as
BEGIN

 DECLARE @fromdate DATE

SET @fromdate =

SELECT convert( varchar(10),fromdate,120) fromdate
FROM Entitlement
WHERE employeeid = @employeeid

DECLARE @enddate DATE

SET @enddate =

SELECT convert ( varchar(10),enddate,120) enddate
FROM entitlement
WHERE employeeid = @employeeid

DECLARE @weekendcount INT

SET @weekendcount =

SELECT Count(*)
FROM Weekend
WHERE weekends BETWEEN @fromdate AND @enddate;

DECLARE @holidayCount INT

SET @holidaycount =

SELECT Count(*)
FROM holidays
WHERE holidaydate BETWEEN @fromdate AND @enddate

DECLARE @Totaldays INT

SET @Totaldays =

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @fromdate, @enddate)

DECLARE @Actualdays INT

SET @Actualdays = @Totaldays - (@weekendcount + isnull(@holidayCount, 0))

DECLARE @recordCount INT

SELECT @recordCount = @Actualdays

IF (@recordCount > 0)
begin 
insert into -- Enter your script here 

END
```

Comment: What error you are getting, are you able to share it please

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_LeaveDays, Line 100 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: i don't know but if i got i will share